# Apagar dados por checkbox

Tags: php, mysql

Bem pessoal estou aqui com um problema eu tenho no meu sistema categorias em que insiro os produtos nas diversas categorias que podem escolher por meio de checkbox só que agora estou a enfrentar um problema e que quero apagar um registo por exemplo:

Tenho uma checkbox selecionada e esta guardada no banco queria que ao desmarcar essa caixa ele apaga-se no banco de dados eu tentei aqui construir o código só que agora não me esta a inserir nem apagar da base de dados.

Codigo Php

```
<?php
                     if($_REQUEST['op']=="editar" && $_REQUEST['valida']=="ok"){
                        if($_REQUEST['op']=="editar"){
                            //$result_existe=mysql_query("select * from colecoes where activo=1");
                            //$row_existe=mysql_query($result_existe);
                            //$result_existe=mysql_query("select * from categorias_estabelecimentos where estabelecimento_id = '".$_REQUEST['id']."' and categoria_slug = '".$row_existe->slug."'");        
                            //if(mysql_num_rows($result_existe)>0){
                                if (!isset($_POST['categoria'])){
                                    foreach($_POST['categoria'] as $entry_categorias_delete){
                                    $categorias_delete= $entry_categorias_delete;
                                        $sql="DELETE FROM categorias_estabelecimentos WHERE estabelecimento_id = '".$_REQUEST['id']."' and categoria_slug='".$categorias_delete."'";
                                        mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error() );
                                    }
                                }
                            }else{
                                $checkBox = $_POST['categoria'];
                                $estabelecimento_id = $_REQUEST['id'];
                                foreach($checkBox as $entry_categorias){
                                $categorias= $entry_categorias;
                                    $query="INSERT INTO categorias_estabelecimentos (estabelecimento_id, categoria_slug) VALUES ('".$estabelecimento_id."', '".$categorias."')";     
                                    mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error() );
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    //}
                    ?>
```

Comment: O que acontece é que no $_POST, você só receberá os que foram "checked", então uma das soluções você pode deletar tudo que está vinculado naquele estabelecimento (DELETE FROM categorias_estabelecimentos WHERE estabelecimento_id = seu_id) e depois inserir tudo novamente... ou caso queira ter mais trabalho, pode verificar um por um;

Comment: pois isso de deletar tudo tinha posto a funcionar mas queria apagar só os que não estão selecionados

Comment: Tente utilizar o operador NOT IN exemplo: DELETE FROM emails WHERE id NOT IN (1,2,3,56); Substitua o que é necessário para o seu caso...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Levando em consideração as opções que o utilizador propôs fiz as modificações onde foram necessárias:

```
if (!isset($_POST['categoria'])){
    $categorias = '' . implode('\',\'', $_POST['categoria']);
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    $sql= "DELETE FROM categorias_estabelecimentos WHERE estabelecimento_id = $id AND categoria_slug NOT IN ($categorias)";
    mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error() );
}
```

Assim ele vai deletar tudo que não está "selecionado" na tela; Não testei, qualquer erro por favor avise.

Comment: O apagar ja funciona direito mas agora não me entro no insert caso seleciona alguma opção

Comment: Já resolvei a questão do insert estava fora do if já funciona valeu pela ajuda

Comment: @CésarSousa Muito bom! Disponha